# How to convert a 4x4 matrix transformation to another coordinate system?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, coordinate-systems

Is there a general method to convert a matrix transformation from one coordinate system to another, so that the resulting transformation looks the same on screen?

For example, there are some transformations in a coordinate system with X right, Y up, and Z toward the viewer. And they need to be converted to a coordinate system with X right, Y away from the viewer, and Z up.

[image]

What would be the operation that needs to be performed for each matrix so that the transformations look the same in the other coordinate system? And is there a general way to construct this operation given the source and destination basis vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the linear transformation can be transformed from one frame to the other one.

Supposed you have transformation $y=Ax$ in the frame $\{0\}$.
This transformation in the new frame $\{1\}$ looks like $Ry=R(A(R^{-1}R)x)= (RAR^{-1})(Rx)$, hence the transformation in the new frame has form $RAR^{-1}$, where $R$ is transformation from $\{0\}$ frame to the frame $\{1\}$.
If this transformation is orthogonal we have $RAR^T$.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, see more details and a complete solution including code here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/203073/how-to-convert-a-4x4-matrix-transformation-to-another-coordinate-system